# Im designing a chess game in HTML,i want to change one charecter from on position to another

Tags: javascript, html

i have designed chess board using buttons.Initially all the values on the button will be null,upon loading the page all the pieces appear on them and the piece of code is as follows

```
<input type="button" id="A8" value="" style="background:#FFE4C4;font-size: 70px;height:90;width:100" onclick="check(this.id)">
```

and in the onLoad function,the ASCII charecter of the chess pieces are assigned  as follows:

```
document.getElementById('A1').value=String.fromCharCode(9814);
```

Now what i want is to change the one piece from a button to another on clicking two buttons.i had tried a lot with the following script

```
function check(clicked_id) {
    var Button_2 = "";
    if (i < 2) {
        i++;
        // alert("i:"+i);        
        if (i == 1) {
            Button_1 = clicked_id;
            B1_val = document.getElementById(Button_1).value;
            alert("B1 Button val:" + B1_val);
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            var Button_2 = clicked_id;
            B2_val = document.getElementById(Button_2).value;
            alert("b1 val:" + B1_val);
            alert("B2 val:" + B2_val);
            B2_val = B1_val;
            B1_val = "";
            alert("B1 val:" + B1_val + "B2 val:" + B2_val);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Only 2 butons should press..i:" + i);
        i = 0;
    }
    // alert("clcked a button:"+clicked_id);
}
```

But the code is not working

Comment: "*But the code is not working*". How?

Comment: what the scenario is,upon clicking a button,the id of the button i will get the id of that button,and when i click on second button that too will get. Now the value in the 2nd button should replace with the 1st buttons value

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move the value from the location of the first click to the location of the second click, then you can do that fairly simply like this:

```
var lastClick;

function check(id) {
    var src, dest;
    if (!lastClick) {
        // no previous click so just store the location of this first click
        lastClick = id;
    } else {
        // move value from lastClick id to new id
        src = document.getElementById(lastClick);
        dest = document.getElementById(id);
        dest.value = src.value;
        src.value = "";
        lastClick = null;
    }
}
```

I assume that a real application would need all sorts of error handling that doesn't let you put a piece on top of another piece, ignores first clicks on empty spaces, enforces only legal moves, etc...

Comment: YA..i know but am not getting how to complete this application,ur code is working to move..can u please help me to complete this..

Comment: @RajeshTamire - we're not going to write all your code for you.   We've answered this question.  If you have a new question, you can post that as a new question, but please be very specific about what you want help with.  It is better to ask how to do something specific and be very clear in your question rather than ask someone to write a whole program for you.

Comment: ya i got it,i too dont ask someone to write whole program